# Why does the text before the loading state appear for 1/2 sec after the loading state ends and the text changes? ( Render problem )

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component, rendering

I have this Button component which displays a spinner when loading = true, to handle loading states, the switch right here is from track to tracking, those are the 2 texts that show up before and after loading.
I'm using the devTools to see the state changing, but the problem is that right after loading=false the spinner stops and just for a second after switching to "tracking" it shows s the word "track" again.
Here's the code:

```
// Following
    const isTracked = computed((): boolean =>
      store.state.user.following.includes(userID.value)
    )
    const isLoadingTracking = ref(false)
    const handleTracking = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        isLoadingTracking.value = true
        if (isTracked.value) await unfollow(userID.value)
        else await follow(userID.value)
        store.dispatch('getProfileData')
      } catch (err) {
        store.commit('notify', { key: 'error', status: 'ERROR' })
      } finally {
        isLoadingTracking.value = false
      }
    }
```

Comment: From what you describe, there is a short period of time after loading when both `isLoadingTracking` and `isTracked` are `false`. That might be due to setting `isLoadingTracking` to `false` too soon (e.g: before the response has been parsed and applied). The problem with your question, in current form, is that we have no way of knowing, because you're showing us the button, instead of showing us the code responsible for setting the values of `isLoadingTracking` and `isTracked`. That's where the problem is.

Comment: You right bro! sorry, I'm uploading the code where the loading change  under the Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.dispatch('getProfileData')` is asynchronous code.

This means that, technically, the `finally {}` block executes before the code in your `getProfileData` action finishes.

To fix it, place an `await` in front of `store.dispatch('getProfileData')`:

```js
      try {
        isLoadingTracking.value = true
        if (isTracked.value) await unfollow(userID.value)
        else await follow(userID.value)
        await store.dispatch('getProfileData')
      } catch (err) {
        store.commit('notify', { key: 'error', status: 'ERROR' })
      } finally {
        isLoadingTracking.value = false
      }
```

Alternate syntax for the above block:

```js
      try {
        isLoadingTracking.value = true
        await (isTracked.value ? unfollow : follow)(userID.value)
        await store.dispatch('getProfileData')
      } catch (err) {
        store.commit('notify', { key: 'error', status: 'ERROR' })
      } finally {
        isLoadingTracking.value = false
      }
```